# Why do I get errors migrating a Ruby site to a new server?

Tags: ruby, mongrel

I am trying to migrate a Ruby server to a new one. I see in its `mongrel.log` file the errors:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in gem_original_require: no such file to load -- yahoo-weather (MissingSourceFile)
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in require
from /home/dianahot/rails_apps/dianahotels/config/initializers/included_libraries.rb:9
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in load_without_new_constant_marking
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.14/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:173:in load
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:622:in load_application_initializers
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:621:in each
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:621:in load_application_initializers
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:176:in process
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in send
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.14/lib/initializer.rb:113:in run
from /home/dianahot/rails_apps/dianahotels/config/environment.rb:12
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in gem_original_require
from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in require
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/rails.rb:147:in rails
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:113:in cloaker_
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in call
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:149:in listener
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:99:in cloaker_
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in call
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/configurator.rb:50:in initialize
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in new
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:84:in run
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/../lib/mongrel/command.rb:212:in run
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/bin/mongrel_rails:281
from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23:in load
from /usr/bin/mongrel_rails:23
```

What does those lines mean?

---

EDIT:

I tried to manually install the yahoo-weather gem, and I got the following error:

```
gem install yahoo-weather
Fetching: nokogiri-1.5.2.gem (100%)
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing yahoo-weather:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/bin/ruby
        --with-zlib-dir
        --without-zlib-dir
        --with-zlib-include
        --without-zlib-include=${zlib-dir}/include
        --with-zlib-lib
        --without-zlib-lib=${zlib-dir}/lib
        --with-iconv-dir
        --without-iconv-dir
        --with-iconv-include
        --without-iconv-include=${iconv-dir}/include
        --with-iconv-lib
        --without-iconv-lib=${iconv-dir}/lib
        --with-xml2-dir
        --without-xml2-dir
        --with-xml2-include
        --without-xml2-include=${xml2-dir}/include
        --with-xml2-lib
        --without-xml2-lib=${xml2-dir}/lib
        --with-xslt-dir
        --without-xslt-dir
        --with-xslt-include
        --without-xslt-include=${xslt-dir}/include
        --with-xslt-lib
        --without-xslt-lib=${xslt-dir}/lib


Gem files will remain installed in /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
root@server2 [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems]# % gem install yahoo-weather
-bash: fg: %: no such job
root@server2 [/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems]#
```

Answer (score 1):

At a guess, you're missing the yahoo-weather gem.

I'd highly recommend you use [bundler](http://gembundler.com) - it makes it a lot easier to deploy an app onto a new machine with consistent versions of all its dependencies.

Comment: Thnx I'll the bundler gem later, I'll try to install the yahoo-weather manually...

Answer (score 0):

The Yahoo-weather gem failed to install, because its dependency on Nokogiri failed. And that happened because:

```
libxslt is missing.  please visit http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help with installing dependencies.
```

From the pathnames listed in the error output, I suspect you're on a Linux system. You'll need to make sure you have the appropriate libxml and libxslt installed. The Nokogiri page should help sort that out.

Comment: Yes, I learned that the hard way. Unfortunately I don't have the rights on the server to install libraries, so I gess it's a dead end for now. Thanks for the help.